# How to check if any option in select box equal any option in another select box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select box, both of them have options that filled automatically via lookup from database. i try to check if any of options in select box no. 2 is equal any options in select box no 1 . if true delete this option from select box no 1, if fals keep it in both.

i find the following code while searching but it not working with me:

```
var exists = false;
  $('#select-box2 option').each(function(){
   if (this.value == $('#select-box1 option').val()) {
    exists = true;
    return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
  $('#select-box2 option').each(function(){  //loop option #select-box2
      var sb2_option=$(this);
       $('#select-box1 option').each(function(){  //loop option #select-box1
           var sb1_option=$(this);
           if(sb2_option.val()==sb1_option.val()){
               console.log('exist!!! #select-box1=>'+sb1_option.val()+' #select-box2=>'+sb2_option.val());
               sb2_option.remove();  //or  sb1_option.remove();  - for delete option
           }
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="select-box1">
  <option value="1">test 1</option>
  <option value="2">test 2</option>
  <option value="3">test 2</option>
  <option value="4">test 4</option>
  <option value="5">test 5</option>
</select>


<select id="select-box2">
  <option value="5">test 5</option>
  <option value="6">test 6</option>
  <option value="7">test 7</option>
  <option value="7">test 8</option>
  <option value="9">test 9</option>
</select>
```